# Composite not Working on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: touchscreen, composite-video

Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Noobs installation
Then Emulation Station

There is an official Rasberry pi touch screen attached by the ribon cable and 4 jumper wires to the Gpio.  I used different power and ground lines than the documentation stated because the power and ground right next to each other are running my cooling fan.  I cannot get the touch screen to work either (not sure if related).  It displays just fine, but no touch response.  If by some chance this is related and there is a solution for that too--great.  If not I do not need the touch.

I have updated and upgraded software.
I read another thread that indicated the Noobs install is to blame
sdtv=0 has been un-commented in my config.txt
Hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1 has been added to my config.txt
hdmi_force_hotplug=1 has been commented out.

Power Supply is 2.5amp, but I am gettting intermittent under voltage warnings.  3.0 amp power supply arrives tomorrow.  Could this be causing the issue?

Cable (3.5 to RCA) has been tested on a known good Rasberry Pi 3 B, and I get picture out from that unit just fine and in craptastic composite style--but that old feel is half the fun.  (It does not have the touch screen attached to it when I test for composite out)

I get a black screen from the composite with some walking down of lighter areas?  Basically black but just a little bit of lighter shading in the blackness that is just enough for me to no believe its my imagination.

Anything else I should try?  I have actually purchased another 3B+ that I will change out with my current one tomorrow.  I actually built this pi into something so that is a pain, but at this point I can't imagine anything but hardware failure.... except user error.  What am I missing?

UPDATE

Power supply does not make a difference (fixed under voltage issue but nothing else); as removing yellow and green GPIO cables did not; as replacing Pi Board with a new one did not.  I'm at a loss here.  Next step is to do a fresh install--will keep updated.

FINAL UPDATE

I had the DVI cable attached and thus... No SDTV.  Cannot run the two at once according to the reasberrypi.org.

Comment: Is your TV with composite input PAL or NTSC?

Comment: With a RPiB+, RPiA+, RPi2B RPi3B, RPi3B+, RPi3A+, RPiZ or RPiZW you ONLY need the power and ground wires for the official RPF touch screen. The green & yellow wires are only needed on an RPi1B or RPi1A

Comment: Codermike; it is a NTSC I believe--i'm in the us and the Raspberry Pi 3 B that does work has "sdtv=0" in its config.  But I confess this is my first dealings with PAL/NTSC.  I'm in the US, and the TV is for the US market.  If I got that wrong please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Dougie, thank you so much.  Going to remove those two wires and see if it helps either of my two problems!

Comment: As a side note, new power supply cured under voltage, but nothing else.

Comment: I took off the Yellow and Green Wires, but that fixed nothing else.  Trying new Pi 3B+ now.  Fingers crossed

Comment: I have now tried a second Raspberry Pi3B+ board.  Assembled it on an antistatic mat; same problems.  Also, as a side note because I don't think I mentioned it before, I have tried it without the touch screen attached and also got nothing but black screen.

Since I think hardware has been eliminated as a problem, I am thinking software.  I must have done something wrong.  I think I am going to try a new install.  Any suggestions on the best way to make sure I get this done right?  Perhaps I should not use NOOBS?